# Experience Analytics page views and visits much lower than expected

Tags: experience-analytics

I have custom analytics which tracks page views and it seems to wildly differ from what Experience Analytics reports. For higher volume pages it seems to be 30% to 60% lower. For low volume pages (i.e. less than 500 visits per month) it can be off by orders of magnitude, with some days having 0 visits even though I know for a fact that is wrong.

I have followed the [xDB troubleshooting guide](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445) and the results have not improved.

Is there some potential config issue or other explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue was because I had the **Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Reduce.config** enabled. Disabling this and performing an reporting DB rebuild improved the discrepancy of high volume pages and fixed the issue with low volume pages.

The rest of the discrepancy can be explained along the lines of [this kb article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/164757), and due to the fact that it's not clear what the difference between a sitecore interaction (page visit) and a sitecore page view is. Pages can be viewed multiple times during a single interaction.